# Jmeter Javascript Switch Statement Always Matches Default

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I have been looking in both Jmeter and Javascript forums and can't figure out why this case statement is always matching to the default and I wondered if it was a Jmeter condition that I was missing.

I don't think it is a data problem. The URLTYPE_ variable is being set by a CSV input. Here are two lines from it.

```
Thumbnail,XXXXXX/XXXXXX,
Caption,XXXXXXXX/XXXXXX,
```

Code Snippet :

```
var t = vars.get("URLTYPE_");
log.info("starting");
log.info(t);
switch (t)
{
case "Thumbnail":
    vars.put("CGIURL", "thumbres");
    vars.put("LBURL", "thumb");
    log.info("thumb");
    break;
case "Caption":
    vars.put("CGIURL", "capt");
    vars.put("LBURL", "c");
    log.info("c");
    break;
default:
    vars.put("CGIURL", "thumbres");
    vars.put("LBURL", "thumb");
    log.info("Default");
    break;
} 
log.info("stopping");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using if clauses instead of case with == comparison.

Comment: That works. It appears to me that this is a bug with switch string compare in jmeter 2.8.

Comment: hello, no because there is no jmeter logic at all , it's all javascript evaluation by rhino implementation

Comment: I am not sure how BSF relates to rhino but it seems odd that this isn't mentioned anywhere else. I haven't been registered long enough to upvote even if it deserves one.